# get quarter of current date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the quarter of current date for this year. The year starts from april 2013.

As i have to fetch the data for the current quarter.
Say from april 2013

Comment: what have you attempted? Did you try searching?

Comment: @ Nenad Zivkovic wel i was expecting a date function name to use . Since this not a super complex question..

Comment: Perhaps it's not complex, but it is very unclear what are you asking for and expecting. Have you explained it better in the question, you would've probably got an answer a long time ago. I'd be glad to help you.

Comment: @ Nenad Zivkovic i am sorry to say what more would you expect.. and also i got an answer.. i had put his quick question for a very quick answer... since i did not have time to google the answer myself.. wel anyways.. i assume stack overflow is for quick answers(in case of simple once).. though might be opposite for the complex once. I expected a quick solution of method i have to use.. And flanging me down on this question.. i am not sure what to post on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use datepart if you have quarters specified as 1,2,3 and 4 as:

```
declare @date date = getdate()

select case when  datepart(MM, @date) IN (4,5,6) then 'Q1' 
            when  datepart(MM, @date) IN (7,8,9) then 'Q2'
            when  datepart(MM, @date) IN (10,11,12) then 'Q3' 
            when  datepart(MM, @date) IN (1,2,3) then 'Q4' 
       end as Quater
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateadd method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to dynamically construct dates or explicitly define the date  range.